# Is this example of recursion correct?

Tags: c, recursion, iteration

```
int main() {
    int num;

    printf("Enter a number\n");
    scanf(" %d", &num);

    num = prime(num);

    if (num == 0)
        printf("This is not a prime number");

    if (num == 1)
        printf("This is a prime number");
}

prime(int num) {
    static i = 2;

    if (num % i == 0)
        return 0;

    prime(i + 1);

    return 1;
}
```

Note that it doesn't work in some compilers.

I want to know if we can call it recursion or not.

Specifically, I am confused if calling prime function like `prime(i + 1)` falls under recursion or not.

Comment: Of course it is, why wouldnt it be???

Comment: Yes it is. When a function calls itself, directly or indirectly, it is recursive by definition. That said, as @UnholySheep notes, this function is nonsensical. It is still recursive though.

Comment: Why didn't you specify a return type for `prime`? And why are you not using the return value in your "recursive" call?

Comment: By the way, the reason *"it doesn't work in some compilers"* is because since C99 you need to declare a function before using it (either full definition or forward declaration) **and** you need to specify its return type. - so you should write your code to be compatible with newer versions of the standard.

Comment: Your recursive function is correct, its just that it does find whether the number is prime or not.

Comment: @UnholySheep The default return type is int that's why I didn't specify it.
I'm new to it so I don't have much experience. And I tried specifying the return type and also declared the function but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code your were passing `i` as argument in further recursive calls which was logically not correct. You need to pass the number as well as a divisor the function `prime`. The below code is one of the way to implement your logic.

```
#include<stdio.h>

 int prime(int num,int i)
 {

    if(num==i)
        return 1;

    if(num % i == 0)
        return 0;

    return prime(num,i+1);
 }



 int main()

 {

   int num;

   printf("Enter a number\n");
   scanf(" %d", &num);
   if(num>1){
      num = prime(num,2);
      if(num == 0)
         printf("This is not a prime number");

      else
          printf("This is a prime number");
    }
    else printf("This is neither prime nor composite");
    return 0;
  }
```

Note the no input validation is performed and it is assumed that user will input only positive integers.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling prime with `i` during the recursive call, which is not the actual value you want to check for prime, that is the reason it is not working!
It will return `0` for multiples of `2` only otherwise it will be stuck in an infinite loop.

```
int prime(int num) {
    static i = 2;
    if(num % i == 0)
        return 0;

    prime(i + 1); // passing i instead of num
    return 1;
}
```

You can pass the divisor along with the number, and increase the divisor with `1` in every recursive call.

```
int prime(int num, int d) {
    if(num == 0 || num == 1 || num % d == 0)
        return 0;
    if(d <= sqrt(num)) // num will not be divisible by d > sqrt(num)
        prime(num, d + 1);
    return 1;
}
```

Initially call `prime` with divisor `2` like `prime(num, 2)` in `main`.